# Flutter: ListTile Positioned over an image - throws exception - BoxConstraints forces an infinite width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a full screen image and I want to show a `ListTile` over it, positioned at the bottom of the screen. I keep on getting exception `BoxConstraints forces an infinite width`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Image(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          image: Image.file(File(filePath)).image,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
        ),
        Container(
          child: const Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://image_sample.jpg'),
              ),
              title: Text("Sample Text"),
              subtitle: Text('@user1'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Exception obtained is:

[image]

I've tried to constraint the ListTile using ConstrainedBox, but still keep getting exception. If I remove the ListTile and use a simple Text widget, it works fine. I understand ListTile has unbounded constraints, so how to make it work?

Comment: Can you include more snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `ListTile` widget expands horizontally as long as possible, so you should add a constrained width for the parent widget.

In your case you should define width for the `Positioned` widget.

```
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, //give positioned a max width
          child: const ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://image_sample.jpg'),
            ),
            title: Text("Sample Text"),
            subtitle: Text('@user1'),
          ),
        ),
```